# TPM2 - Create a persistent primary key under Windows with Tbsip_Submit_Command

Tags: windows, encryption, tpm

Playing with my TPM chip using [Tbsip_Submit_Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542648(v=vs.85).aspx) I can see that Windows analyses the frames I'm sending to it.

To make this simple I'm using the shutdown command.

For instance I tried to send a TPM_CC_Shutdown with TPM_SU_CLEAR in argument. So the frame is => 80 01 00 00 00 0C 00 00  01 45 00 00

To make it more detailled and explained :

```
80 01         is TPM_ST_NO_SESSIONS
00 00 00 0C   size of the frame
00 00 01 45   TPM_CC_Shutdown
00 00         is TPM_SU_CLEAR
```

Windows responds to me => 80 01 00 00 00 0A 80 28 04 00
Again to make it more detailled:

```
80 01         is TPM_ST_NO_SESSIONS
00 00 00 0A   size of the command
80 28 04 00   error code 0x80280400 => TPM_E_COMMAND_BLOCKED
```

I found that error code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542648(v=vs.85).aspx).
So apparentlty Windows cuts me off and drops my command. I can understand it doesn't want the TPM to be powerred down, but I get the same result for a command where I want to create a primary key and save it inside the chip.

So I have a chip but if I want to use it directly I can't, I'm forced to use the Cryptography API: Next Generation but in my case I can't.

Anyone has anything to help me?
May be I can directly communicate with the chip coding a driver and bypass Windows layers (If anyone has an idea on how to do this) ?
Or may be it is possible to configure a value in registry to have windows let me do what I want with my TPM chip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa965898.aspx) commands are blocked or not depending on your configuration. It is possible to unlock commands, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi b3nj1, I am also having the same problem here. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the book "[A Practical Guide to TPM 2.0](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-6584-9.pdf)"
on Chapter 10 Keys (pg 126), it says:

> The TPM library specification includes symmetric encryption keys that can be used for general-purpose encryption such as AES. It’s uncertain whether TPM vendors will include these functions, due to potential export restrictions. **The commands are optional in the PC Client platform specification. Historically, TPM vendors haven’t implemented optional TPM features.**

You can use command `TPM2_GetCapability` with the parameter `TPM_CAP_COMMANDS` to retrieve a list of implemented commands. If the command you want to use is not listed, it might not be implemented by the TPM vendor.

See in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/testref/tpm-v20-command-and-signal-profile for a list of **Included** and **Optional** Commands from Windows point of view.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the commands are blocked by Windows so it's not a matter of if the command is supported byt the tpm or not.

Comment: I edited and added the Windows profile. But at the end, the Windows TPM driver will call `TPM2_GetCapability` and see if TPM supports the command or not, so they are connected.

Comment: Interesting, I will check this when I get time! Thx!